# How to compare two multi-area ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have two variables of type Range, say r1 and r2. How can I check if they are the same range? If it is a single cell or a single contiguous range of cells it is easy enough (we can assume that they are on the same sheet):

```
If r1.Address = r2.Address Then
```

But what if they are multi-area ranges (r1.Areas.Count > 0)? In most situations the above line of code will still work, but the order that the areas' addresses appear in the address of r1 and r2 may be different. There are situations for example where you will have the following:

```
Debug.Print r1.Address
Debug.Print r2.Address
```

can result in

```
"$A$1,$B$2"
"$B$2,$A$1"
```

They are clearly the same range but the condition in the IF statement above will evaluate to false.

Ideally I would like to say IF r1 = r2 Then, but that won't work. Maybe I can try something with Union...

Edit:

I have also tried

```
If r1 Is r2 Then
```

but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple double loop:

```
Sub SameCheck(R1 As Range, R2 As Range)
Dim r As Range

For Each r In R1
    If Intersect(r, R2) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "not the same"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next r

For Each r In R2
    If Intersect(r, R1) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "not the same"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next r

MsgBox "the same"
End Sub
```

Tested like:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Call SameCheck(Range("A1:Z100"), Range("B9"))
    Call SameCheck(Range("A1:C3"), Range("A1:C3"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across a good solution elsewhere on SO:

```
If (Intersect(r1,r2).Cells.Count = r1.Cells.Count) AND Intersect(r1,r2).Cells.Count = r2.Cells.Count Then
```

This works because if the two ranges are not exactly the same then then intersection of the two ranges will always have fewer cells than at least one of them.

**Edit**

Based on Rusan's comment below it is clear there are situations where the condition above will evaluate to False even though r1 and r2 are the "same". I use quotation marks because it needs to be defined what I mean by saying they are the "same" range: if you draw a border around the outer edges of r1 and a border around the outer edges of r2 then the borders must be along the exact same path.

As Rusan pointed out, an issue arises if one or both of r1 and r2 have overlapped cells within them. Therefore we need to "de-overlap" them first:

```
Public Function GetNonOverlappedRange(r As Range) As Range

Dim cell As Range, area As Range, newRange As Range

For Each area In r.Areas
    For Each cell In area
        If newRange Is Nothing Then
            Set newRange = cell
        Else
            If Intersect(cell, newRange) Is Nothing Then
                Set newRange = Union(newRange, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

Set GetNonOverlappedRange = newRange

End Function
```

Then

```
Set r3 = GetNonOverlappedRange(r1)
Set r4 = GetNonOverlappedRange(r2)

If (Intersect(r3,r4).Cells.Count = r3.Cells.Count) AND Intersect(r3,r4).Cells.Count = r4.Cells.Count Then
    'If this is true then r1 and r2 are the "same" range
```

I should point out that Gary's Student's answer below provides a correct answer to my question and I will mark it as the right answer, but I thought it would be useful to construct the "de-overlapping" function above anyway because I can see many situations where it would be needed.

Comment: Based on @Gary's Students example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864363/constructing-a-range-containing-a-cell-multiple-times), it is possible to construct pathological ranges, from calls to `Union`, for which `.Cells.Count` does not work correctly. It counts overlapping cells anywhere between 1 and n times, where n is the number of times a cell is *overlapped*. The example given in the link shows that `r1=Union(Range("A1:B1"),Range("B1:B5"),Range("B1:C2"))` and `r2=Union(Range("A1:C1"),Range("B2:C2"),Range("B3:B5"))` consist of 11 cells and 8 cells, resp. `Intersect(r1,r2)`=9

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm... interesting. Seems to me this could lead to issues in lots of situations, sor example when your code is relying on user selections or named ranges. I think this requires the ranges to be "De-Overlapped" before doing anything else.

Comment: Yes, that correct. You can use Gary's Students explicit double loop. But if you have to compare very large ranges - differing by only a few cells, you can use a slightly more scalable solution based upon dictionaries. I'll post something, if you don't already know what I mean.