# Constructing a `Range` containing a cell multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I can easily construct a Range in which the same cell appears twice (in this case cell B1):

```
Sub IAmTheCount()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("A1:B1")
    Set r2 = Range("B1:B2")
    Set r3 = Union(r1, r2)
    MsgBox r3.Count
End Sub
```

How can I construct a range in which the same cell appears more than twice??

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are trying to do?

Comment: @brettdj I am attempting to construct a range in which the same cell appears three times.

Comment: I suspect a cell can only be twice in the Union, if you unite a column vector with a row vector and the cell is in both vectors.

Comment: @AxelRichter ...........Thank you........if no one can answer this, I will delete the question in a few days.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Why would you want/need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I am inside your head or not with this, but this seems to count and include cell B1 three times and act as an explicit range.

```
Sub IAmTheCount()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("A1:B1")
    Set r2 = Range("B1:B5")
    Set r3 = Range("B1:C2")
    Set r4 = Union(r1, r2, r3)
    MsgBox r4.Count & " - " & r4.Address
    r4.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```